# Flattening data using PLSQL in Oracle 10G

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Having three tables as follows:

```
Client (Client_Id)
Order (Order_Id, Client_Id)
OrderItem (OrderItem_Id, Order_Id)
```

how do  I go about getting a list of the `ClientId`'s along with a comma separated list of all OrderItem_Id's (serialized into a string) made made by the client?

**Note** Clients can't have multiple orders.

Here's an example:

Inputs:

```
Client: 100
Order: 50, 100
OrderItem: [{1, 50}, {2, 50}, {3, 50}]
```

Expected result: `100, "1,2,3"`

I'm using Oracle 10G (soon to be moved to 11G), no `java`, no cursors, no temp tables please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WM_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967796/oracle-function-replicate-wm-concat) if < 11g or [LIST_AGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) or possibly [XMLAGG](http://www.dautkhanov.com/2010/08/listagg-alternative-in-10g.html)

```
Select client_ID, List_Agg(OrderItem_ID, ', ')
from ORDER O
INNER JOIN ORDERITEM OI on OI.Order_ID = O.Order_ID
```

OR

```
Select client_ID, wm_concat(OrderItem_ID)
from ORDER O
INNER JOIN ORDERITEM OI on OI.Order_ID = O.Order_ID
```

Note: WM_CONCAT is an undocumented function, use at your own risk; albeit extremely useful.

Comment: are they mutually exclusive - can I use WM_CONCAT with oracle 11G?

Comment: WM_Concat works in 11g; again its undocumented/unsupportted so LIST_AGG would be prefered in an 11g envt; however I understand the need to code in 10g w/ ease of portability to 11g.  just know that if you use wm_concat, and it breaks at some point; oracle is going to tell you to use list_Agg.  While a bit more painful to use XMLAgg may be best given your current DB version dilemma.